# Is this code correctly synchronized?

Tags: c++, synchronization, stdasync

I wonder if this code is fine or not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
struct Foo
{
    Foo()
        :m_a(0)
    {
    }

    int m_a;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    auto handle =
        std::async( std::launch::async, 
                [](Foo* f) { std::cout << f->m_a << '\n'; } ,
                &f
              );

    handle.get();
}
```

I believe `m_a` should be protected by a synchronization mechanism but my colleague says it is not necessary.

**EDIT**: To clarify my question: I am worried that the STORE operation from the constructor of `Foo()` happens after the LOAD operation from the other thread. I can't see what mechanism prevents the compiler from executing those instruction in this order.

**EDIT**: I believe an enthusiastic compiler could decide to inline the constructor, and delay the STORE operation for after the CALL operation to `std::async`. In which case the second thread could access `m_a` before it has been committed to memory.

Comment: Nothing else is writing to `f` or reading from it in `main`, so there's nothing to synchronise. But it would help if you listed some of the arguments on each side.

Comment: @juanchopanza There is something else writing to `f`: it's destructed automatically, i.e. the access to `f->m_a` should better not happen after `f` was destroyed.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe It is destroyed after the call to `handle.get()`. So I meant there's no read-write in `main()` while the async operation is being performed. Now, it this wasn't safe, `std::async` would be pretty damn useless.

Comment: I'll bet someone will find the relevant section of the standard and it will say that it is guaranteed that any thread created by `std::async` can see any changes made by the thread that invoked it prior to that invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correctly synchronised.

From the specification for `async`, C++11 30.6.8/5:

> the invocation of `async` synchronizes with the invocation of `f`.

where `f` is the function argument to `async` (the lambda in your example).

Initialisation of `f.m_a` is sequenced before the call to `async`, and therefore before any access by the asynchronous function.

Furthermore,

> the completion of the function f is sequenced before the shared state is made ready.

so the access must happen before the call to `get()` returns, and therefore before the object is destroyed.

Comment: I am more concerned about the access to `m_a` within the lambda function in the other thread. What guarantees that the STORE operation has completed?

Comment: @qdii: Sorry, I misread the question. My answer doesn't answer it.

Comment: @qdii: This should answer the question now. Sorry for the confusion.